# Django redirect with parameters not in the URL

Tags: django, url, redirect

Although this may seem like a question that has been asked before, answers I've seen all include having the parameters in the URL which is not what I want.

What I currently have is a set of URL's that work as intended but don't follow conventions and aren't clear to look at. I'll skip all the background of what I am doing since it isn't necessary to understand nor help me find a solution.

I have a URL in the following format: `exchange/university/<int:univID>/personal-info` which is a page specifically for users to enter their personal information on. This page has a button which will redirect users to a new page which is where my problem lies.

The current redirect URL looks like this: `exchange/university/<int:univID>/<int:studID>/department` and the redirect command within my code looks like this: `return redirect('/exchange/university/'+str(univID)+'/'+str(studentID)+'/department')`

What I would like is simply to pass the student ID as a parameter into the redirect and not have it appear in the URL since having it in the URL doesn't follow the site structure where users enter information with regards to a specific university and therefore, for me, only the university ID is necessary to understand what the page is supposed to do (and also, having another ID in the URL can make things confusing in the long run)

If you feel I'm over-complicating my life trying to do this and that this problem isn't really a problem, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. How will the parameter get to the next page if it's not in the URL?

Comment: I have access to the student ID in the view and that's where it's passed into the url but I would prefer to pass it simply as a parameter and get it on the redirected page that way

Comment: But that doesn't make sense. What kind of "parameter"?

Comment: In this case simply an integer that I want to be able to use on the next page

Comment: That wasn't what I meant. The way views get parameters is via the URL. How else do you want it to work?